# Can I programmatically exit a Firebird script

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5, ibexpert

Consider the following script:

```
set term ^;

exit
^

execute block
as
begin
   execute statement 'this will fail';
end
^
```

The `exit` is perfectly valid and does cause script execution to end. At least in IBExpert where I am testing this. But I want to do this programmatically.

```
set term ^;

execute block
as
begin
   if (exists(select 1 from sometable where somevalue = 1)) then begin
      -- This only exits the block, not the script
      exit;
   end
end
^

execute block
as
begin
   execute statement 'this will fail';
end
^
```

Is the `exit` in my first example valid Firebird or is IBExpert handling this itself? Is there a different way to exit the entire script conditionally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the use of `exit` in your script, with using `exit` inside Firebird statements (specifically the `execute block`). The plain `exit` in your script is interpreted by IBExpert as a signal to stop the script.

However when `exit` is part of an `execute block`, it is **not** part of your script, it is part of a statement that is sent to Firebird server for execution, and it does not have effect on the execution of the script itself.

The code in an `execute block` statement is PSQL, where [`EXIT`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-exit) has a specific meaning:

> The `EXIT` statement causes execution of the procedure or trigger to jump to the final `END` statement from any point in the code, thus terminating the program.

Here, *program* is the procedure (an `execute block` is an anonymous procedure) or trigger.

In other words, an `exit` within an `execute block` causes termination of that `execute block`, nothing more.

I don't know if IBExpert supports more advanced scripting options, but you could look at returning a value from the `execute block` and use a condition in your script to exit (if that is possible in IBExpert). Another solution might be to [raise an exception](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-handleexceptions) within the `execute block` (this assumes IBExpert stops the script on errors).

Comment: Yeah, I totally get the difference in the `exit`. I only have it in the execute block as an example. I was hoping there was another keyword similar to how `leave` works with cursors. Something that would break a script fully. I guess it makes sense that there would not be since this is PSQL and it shouldn't communicate back to a script. The reason I thought it might be possible is because exit worked by itself.

Comment: @Paul `exit` by itself works, because that is how IBExpert handles it if it is a statement on its own.

Answer (score 1):

If the script is supposed to be executed only via IBExpert (not other tools like isql or FlameRobin), you can use [IBExpert script extensions](https://www.ibexpert.net/ibe/pmwiki.php?n=Doc.ScriptExecutive#ScriptLangExt).

```
{$IFEXISTS select 1 from sometable where somevalue = 1 }
-- put your script here
{$ENDIF}
```

For example, this is how I write DB upgrade scripts, where each script needs to be executed in a specific order:

```
-- Upgrade db version from 201 to 202
{$IFNOTEXISTS select 1 from DBINFO where DB_VERSION = 201 }
execute block as begin
    exception EX_DB_UPGRADE 'Wrong DB_VERSION';
end;
{$ELSE}
-- <upgrade_script_here>

update DBINFO set DB_VERSION = 202 where DB_VERSION = 201;
commit;
{$ENDIF}
```